# Angular modules and browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify, browserify-shim

I managed to shim angular with this in package.json

```
"browser": {
"angular": "./bower_components/angular/angular.js",
"ngRoute": "./bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js",
},
"browserify": {
   "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"]
}
"browserify-shim": "./config/shim.js"
```

and this in shim.js

```
module.exports = {
  'angular'    :  { 'exports': 'global:angular' },
  'ngRoute' :  { }
};
```

This way I can include angular in a separate script tag and it won't be bundled by browserify. However I can't figure out how to do the same for ngRoute. 
Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do as follows:

1. Remove browserify-shim
2. Use [debowerify](https://github.com/eugeneware/debowerify) in browserify instead
3. Use bower to install angular and angular-route
4. Write an app.js as follows to browserify

```js
require("angular");

require("angular-route");
```